# Where to find factory list in apple serial number

Tags: iphone

In apple products serial number, the first three is "Factory and machine ID", for example, c3 means China, where I can find the whole factory and code comparison table?

Comment: Just out of interest, why do you need it.

Comment: The S/N has been decoded and some websites provide a query service, for example: http://www.appleserialnumberinfo.com/Desktop/index.php and http://www.chipmunk.nl/klantenservice/applemodel.html. Both return a wealth of information. The first URL returned: `Build Country: This unit was built in China` for my Mac S/N, the second: `Factory: C0 (Quanta Computer (Susidiary = Tech Com))`. Unfortunately, the factory table seems to be a well guarded secret.

Comment: my guess is building a superior lookup service for affiliate sales ;)

Comment: Feel free to explain more how a user of Apple products will find this useful. Just like developers calling private API - when something isn't documented publicly, it can be counted on to change and break. The obvious answer is this is merely a spreadsheet somewhere in Cupertino and we're all trying to read tea leaves from limited data.

Comment: Why are we supporting this? It is obvious that Apple does not want this information to be public to protect they OEM status from COPY cats. Someone from China wants to know where each of the components of Apple products is made! Guess why !

Comment: I don't understand the negativity against this Question... It's a perfectly legitimate doubt/curiosity, heck, [can we make a poll](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1564) to see how many of us have non-chinese SN's? USA SN anyone?! @Buscar웃, "Someone from China" seems out of place, what's wrong about it?

Answer (score 4):

Interesting question - a quick search didn't turn up much, but there's a site you can do lookups on: http://www.chipmunk.nl/klantenservice/applemodel.html and a [macrumours forum](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1342999) where a few people have posted their info..

Here's a list of factories mentioned in the forum above (plus mine):

- Factory: DL (China - Foxconn)
- Factory: DM (China - Foxconn)
- Factory: DN (China, Chengdu - Foxconn)
- Factory: C0 (Quanta Computer (Susidiary = Tech Com))

Another site offers lookups, too, but didn't have info for my 2013 MBP: http://www.appleserialnumberinfo.com.  They have some interesting but unrevealing javascript validation for their lookup form..

Answer (score 2):

There is an image attached [in this forum post](http://forums.macrumors.com/showpost.php?p=9687586&postcount=38) which explains a few more details:

[image]

The image was a screenshot taken before Apple asked the site to remove the original article.

Comment: The [original URL](http://everymac.com/ultimate-mac-lookup/how-to-decipher-understand-apple-mac-serial-number-format.html) still exists, but shows a different content. The Internet Archive Wayback Machine [shows that the snapshot is indeed accurate](http://web.archive.org/web/20101113080242/http://www.everymac.com/ultimate-mac-lookup/how-to-decipher-understand-apple-mac-serial-number-format.html).