# Find Mac's "age" in Yosemite

Tags: mac

I upgraded a Mac to OS X Yosemite and would like to find the age (when it's been released). In previous OS it was given here:

[image: Details under Mac OS X Mavericks]

but I can't find it in Yosemite there

[image: Cant find age]

...anyone?

Comment: According to the serial number it's a "MacBook Pro "Core i7" 2.66 15" Mid-2010". I assume you already tried to reboot. Is there anything of interest in `/var/log/system.log` around the time you access "About this Mac"?

Comment: @patrix where do I find the /var index?

Comment: Open Terminal and `sudo less /var/log/system.log`. Or run the Console application

Comment: @patrix nothing I would find helpful

Comment: @patrix but I ran the command and now in the details it shows it, thank you :)

Comment: You run `sudo less...` and now the model is shown in "About this Mac"?

Comment: Yeah maybe it was randomly...

Comment: Are you connected to the Network?  I believe System Information contacts http://support-sp.apple.com to get that info and populate the About this Mac window.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to find the age of a specific Mac?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/91925/is-there-a-way-to-find-the-age-of-a-specific-mac)

Comment: @tron_jones actually I was not, but I did not connect later either so this is not necessarily true

Answer (score 5):

It should be right under the the OS X Yosemite.  Checked 3 different models and all showed in the same place.

[image]

Comment: Well it's not...see new pic in my question

Comment: @Ummsekatze It might be a bug in 10.10 - can you open the app store and install updates until you are at 10.10.1 ?

Answer (score 3):

Or, on the same window, you can go to the *Support* tab and click *Specifications* to get even more information.

[image: About This Mac/Support]

Answer (score 0):

You could also check for your device or any other device when you have the serial number at 
[selfsolfe.apple.com](https://selfsolve.apple.com/agreementWarrantyDynamic.do)